# Magento Reorder Missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Within a customers 'My Orders' section, It seems that the 'Reorder' link is missing. From what I've worked out this is when a product(s) within the order no longer exists or is in stock.

Is anybody aware of how you can enable the re-order link to still appear but to ignore (or display a message) about the missing products, or something similar.

Using Magento 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method responsible for reordering is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_canReorder()`.
This accepts a parameter that ignores if the product is in stock, but it doesn't ignore if the product is missing.
The method `_canReorder` is called by `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::canReorder()`. This is actually called to see if you can reorder. I recommend overriding this and changing the parameter value.
By default it looks like this:

```
public function canReorder()
{
    return $this->_canReorder(false);
}
```

Your version can look like this:

```
public function canReorder()
{
    return $this->_canReorder(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled the reorder functionality in the Magento backend:

`System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Reorder`

This option should be set to `enabled`.